# scale in jssor slider

Tags: slider, scale, jssor

i'm fine with this scale code:

```
var MAX_WIDTH = 2000;

function ScaleSlider() {
    window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
}

ScaleSlider();
$Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);
$Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", ScaleSlider);
$Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
```

but it makes a problem for slider.
actually my slider option is this:

```
var jssor_1_options = {
    $AutoPlay: 0,
    $SlideWidth: 200,
    $SlideSpacing: 5,
    $Loop: 0,
    $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
        $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,
        $Steps: 3
    }
}
```

that means it shows many images together because of "$SlideWidth: 200"

i used 12 images. but when i run the slider, it shows just about 6 or 7 image, and it thinks that the slider is finished. cant slide more than these 6 or 7.

and u should know when i delete "$Loop: 0" it works correctly.

this is a sample of my code:
https://code.sololearn.com/WQ80P1R1Un0J/#

Comment: Please send me an url of your page, let me have a look. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @jssor [link](http://s9.picofile.com/file/8334084826/sample.html.html) just click on the red button which is in middle of page. thanks a lot.

Comment: sorry, I can't see a slider on your page.

Comment: @jssor yes. you are right. it was a download link. but now I write the code on "code play ground". please visit this link: [link](https://code.sololearn.com/WQ80P1R1Un0J/#). so many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your demo, it works.

**Edit**
The responsive code is missing in the `ScaleSlider` function

```
jssor_mostsold_slider_init = function() {
    var jssor_1_options = {
        $AutoPlay: 0,
        $SlideWidth: 200,
        $SlideSpacing: 5,
        $Loop: 0,
        $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,
            $Steps: 3
        }
    };

    var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor-mostsold-slider", jssor_1_options);

    /*#region responsive code begin*/

    var MAX_WIDTH = 2000;

    function ScaleSlider() {
            window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
    }

    ScaleSlider();
    $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);
    $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", ScaleSlider);
    $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
};
```

See `ScaleSlider` exmaple below,

```
function ScaleSlider() {
    var containerElement = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode;
    var containerWidth = containerElement.clientWidth;

    if (containerWidth) {

        var expectedWidth = Math.min(MAX_WIDTH || containerWidth, containerWidth);

        jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(expectedWidth);
    }
    else {
        window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
    }
}
```

Comment: No. Showing the images is not my problem. I meant there are 12 images, but we can't slide between all of them. We can just see 6 or 7 of them. Do u understand?

Comment: I replaced images, but my problem is not solved. there is 12 images. but we can use "right arrow" just 1 time that pushes the slide 3 step. we can't see all of that 12 images.

Comment: thanks bro. but still does not work correctly. images are so small with this new scale function. I like the previous. that was so good. and images were responsive. only problem was that we cant slide between all of images. you can see your suggested function in: [link](https://code.sololearn.com/WQ80P1R1Un0J/)

Comment: the slide width is 200, the slider width and slides container width is 2000. That's to say, it display 10 slides, make the `slider width` and `slides container width` smaller then

Comment: btw, the `max-width:100%;min-width:100%;` is not necessary, and it doesn't work. please remove it.